# Issue in Login in Page Object Model

Tags: selenium, nunit

I have a use case which denotes below steps
I am trying to implement it using POM in Nunit.

1. Open Login Form
2. Feed the data in the username and password fields using Excel.

   3a. **If the credentials are correct**

   a)Log the test case as passed

   b)Click on Log Off link

4.Close the remaining browser window

3b.**If the credentials are incorrect**

a) Log the test case as failed

b) Clear the username and password textboxes

c) No need to close the browser window.

Now the issue is already driver is instantiated in [Setup] in Main Class.
How do we instantiate the browser window again in case the login is successful.

I am adding the below code

```
Login Object Class
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticePrograms.PageObjectsWithPageFactory
{
public class VSSLoginObjects
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "userNameOldLook")]
    public IWebElement Userid { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@type='password']")]
    public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[contains(text(),'login')]")]
    public IWebElement Btn_Login { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//li[contains(text(),'Login failed')]")]
    public IWebElement Lbl_Login_Failed { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[contains(text(),'Logoff')]")]
    public IWebElement lnk_logoff;


    public VSSLoginObjects()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(DriverInstance.driver, this);
    }

    public void Login_QAPortal()
    {
        Userid.SendKeys("v0c1344");
        Wait.UntilElementDisplayed(DriverInstance.driver, Password);
        Password.SendKeys("welcome5");
        Btn_Login.Click();
        //return new QAPortal_LandingPage_Objects();

    }
    public void Test_Login_QA_Portal()
    {
        String Excel = @"C:\\Selenium Files\\TestData.xlsx";
        int length = ExcelClassTemp.GetRowCount(Excel, 3);
        for (int i = 2; i <= length; i++)
        {

            String data = ExcelClassTemp.ReadExcel(Excel, 3, i, 1);
            String upper_data = data.ToUpper();
            Userid.SendKeys(upper_data);
            Password.SendKeys("Welcome567");
            Btn_Login.Click();

            if (DriverInstance.driver.PageSource.Contains("Trucks Portal"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Credentials" + upper_data + "Passed");
                lnk_logoff.Click();
                DriverInstance.driver.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Credentials" + upper_data + "Failed");
                Userid.Clear();
                Password.Clear();
            }



        }

    }
   }
   }
```

Adding the Main Class

```
Main Class
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

 namespace PracticePrograms.PageObjectsWithPageFactory
 {
public class Tests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void setup()
    {
        DriverInstance.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        DriverInstance.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Go to Url");
        DriverInstance.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();


    }



    [Test]
    public void Perform_VSS_Login()
    {
        VSSLoginObjects login = new VSSLoginObjects();
        login.Test_Login_QA_Portal();

    }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make few changes :

the reference `DriverInstance.driver` declare this as global.

and when you are creating object of VSSLoginObjects in your Test method like :

```
VSSLoginObjects login = new VSSLoginObjects();
```

Pass the reference of `DriverInstance.driver` in `new VSSLoginObjects()`;

Something like : `VSSLoginObjects(reference of driver object)` .

Explanation : When you create the object of any class and pass the reference , a **parameterized** **constructor** will be called.

I believe this constructor will be called:

```
 public VSSLoginObjects()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(DriverInstance.driver, this);
    }
```

Comment: My question is
How can we instantiate a new instance of browser window when the login is successful.

Comment: For that you have to use new chromedriver(); because you want to create a new instance(instantiate) of browser. You will have to depende on new keyword for your case.

Comment: Or as you have mentioned you are using page object model then you can return the object of dashboard page after successful login for that the return type of your login method should be dashboard type and you should use return new dashboard(driver) as last line of login method

Comment: Hello Pandey,
I tried in another way but there are some issues during multiple logins.
Frankly speaking i am stuck and don't know how to proceed.
Can u please explain with an example

Comment: See you are doing this :  VSSLoginObjects login = new VSSLoginObjects();   and all I'm saying is to do this :  VSSLoginObjects login = new VSSLoginObjects(DriverInstance.driver)  so that driver reference would be passed to VSSLoginObjects class and if you want to open a new browser when login is successful then you have to use DriverInstance.driver = new ChromeDriver(); there is no other way that you can have a new browser instance with out invoking it. Hope this will be helpful !

Comment: Yes got it.Thanks

Comment: @ManishBTry it out , and update the result here ! Feel free to contact me here if you need any further assistance. I’d be happy to help ;)